# Use a unique_ptr and return a reference or should I use a shared_ptr and make copies if needed

Tags: c++

I have a cache that stores unique ptrs of objects in an unordered map and returns a reference of the object for users of the cache. It works as it should, storing the objects until they go out of scope.

The cache is implemented as follows:

store objects in cache:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename... Args>
void ResourceCache<T>::add(const std::string& name, Args... args)
{
    m_cache->try_emplace(name, std::make_unique<T>(args...));
}
```

get object from cache:

```
template<typename T>
T& ResourceCache<T>::getCachedElement(const std::string& name) const
{
    auto it = m_cache->find(name);

    if(it != m_cache->end())
        return *it->second;

    throw "resource not found";
}
```

But now I walk in to the problem that a reference is not always what I would like to get from the cache, per example:

I have the following object:

```
class GameObject
{
public:
    void translate(const cheetah::Vector3f& position);
protected:
    Quaternion m_rotation;
    Vector3f m_position;
};
```

lets say I want the object to have a Texture, currently the only way for me would be to add a member reference

`Texture& m_texture`

This would result in me having to either

1. Pass a Texture to the constructor for each object, even if they dont need a texture.
2. Create a TexturedGameObject that inherits from the GameObject and adds a Texture member and constructor.
3. Use shared pointers instead of unique pointers and be able to return a copy

**Now my question is**

What would be seen as best practice in this specific situation? should I use one of the above options or have I missed an even better option?

I know my question is not the most specific but I am learning c++ by myself and it would be nice to get someone elses view on this.

Comment: Option 1 would quickly grow out-of-control if you add more stuff. For option 3 I don't understand how you think it will make a difference whether you use `unique_ptr`s or `shared_ptr`s in `m_cache` Option 3 will work immediately without problem if you give the base class a virtual destructor. You just have to template `add` with another parameter for the type to pass to `make_unique`. Could you explain with some more code how you image option 3 to work and what concern you have about option 2?

Comment: If your compiler support C++17, you can use `std::unique_ptr<std::variant<GameObject, Texture>>`

Comment: The `ResourceCache` objects would contain `GameObject`, or `Texture`, or both? How would this use together with `unique_ptr` cause issues?

Comment: What about returning a raw pointer instead of reference? It is almost same with references but it can be `nullptr` so you would not need to pass it to constructor.

Comment: Would a dependency framework like [Google/fruit](https://github.com/google/fruit) be helpful to you ([documentation](https://github.com/google/fruit/wiki))?

Comment: Returning the raw pointer would be an easy way but isnt it also more error prone because I could delete the pointer resulting in possible double deletion?@HanjoungLee

Comment: Does `ResourceCache` hold `Texture`? I assumed that.

Comment: @RickNijhuis Right. But for the reference, it has the same problem.

Comment: If any element are added to the appropriate cache, what is the problem? If you want derived class, then you would only need to have an `addTyped<U>(name, args)` function or `addExisting(name, unique_ptr)` function? Everything else should works as if. However, a `find` function to verify if an object is already in the cache might be useful too.

Comment: @RickNijhuis For both raw pointers or references, they both have dangling-pointer/reference problem but no double-free problem unless you write `delete` code.

Comment: @HanjoungLee Yes I know, dont now why but thought using references was cleaner, it seems getting the raw pointer would be a nice simple solution

Comment: @Phil1970 Looks interesting, I think for now I will get the raw pointer but I will keep this in mind if I get more of these kind of issues

Comment: @HanjoungLee and RickNijuis: I am very confused. How does returning a pointer change anything about the question? What problem does a null pointer solve here? Can you please edit the question with some code demonstrating the problem you seem to have more clearly?

Comment: @walnut Lets say I have a gameobject that if it's initialized it will not have a texture, but through some gameplay element if a certain condition is fullfilled it needs to get a texture(could also be the condition is never fullfilled and a texture is never needed) if I would use a reference texture member I always need to initialize with a texture whereas a pointer member would let me to set a null pointer with the possibility to add a texture later on.

Comment: @walnut When it is a reference, it must be initialized from constructor. That would forces to create a dummy texture object. I think it would be better to set nullptr to express absence of the texture. It is just about that, I'm also trying to find out what he wants to solve, as well.

Comment: @HanjoungLee and RickNijhuis: Ah ok, I thought the suggestion was to return a pointer from `getCachedElement`. That would make no difference at all. Yes, if you want to optionally add the texture to an object later, then a pointer member (initialized to `nullptr`), rather than a reference one, is the way to go. It was not clear that this is the problem. It seemed that the problem was that some objects are going to have a texture and some objects are *never* going to have a texture. In that case inheritance is the correct approach (specific performance considerations aside).

Comment: @walnut part of the question comes from me not fully understanding smart pointers, I was under the impression that getting the raw pointer was seen as bad practice what led me to trying to find a way arround it resulting in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ResourceCache` holds `Texture`, here's my thoughts. There does not seem to be one best solution in general.

1. Pass a Texture to the constructor for each object, even if they dont need a texture.

   - You would need to pass a dummy object so if you want to go with this way, I would suggest keeping it as a raw pointer instead
   - By doing this you can check if it really has a pointer or not since it can be `nullptr`
   - NOTE Either reference or pointer, you should make sure that `ResourceCache` outlives all `GameObject` - the lifetimes must be managed manually
2. Create a TexturedGameObject that inherits from the GameObject and adds a Texture member and constructor.

   - This could be an option but I think this is more a design issue
3. Use shared pointers instead of unique pointers and be able to return a copy

   - This would work fine
   - Safe (no issues like double-deletion/dangling-pointers)
   - Shared pointer has overhead